# The L6218E Error when calling VxGUI Constructor

Tags: c++, verifone

I am trying to compile using Vrxcc Compiler in VeriFone sdk.
when i want to create a graphical application for Vx675 pose Payment, The compiler show this error

> error : L6218E: Undefined symbol VxGUI::VxGUI() (referred from Main.o)

Main.cpp is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <svc.h>
#include <svc_gui.h>

void main()
{
    VxGUI *m_GUIObj;
    m_GUIObj = new VxGUI(); 
}
```

And the MakeFile is

```
#
################### Paths   ##################
#

ACTIncludes = $(EVOACT)include
EOSIncludes = $(EOSSDK)\include
GUIIncludes  =  $(GUISDK)\Include 
CardslotInclude=$(VCARDSLOT)\Include
DTKTOOLS=C:\eVoAps\Tools

###################  App Source Paths   ##################
SrcDir = .


################### Compiler/Linker/Outhdr Output Paths ##################
ObjDir = .\vobj
OutDir = .\vbin


###################for release...##################
ACTStaticLibraries = $(EVOACT)\Output\RV\Files\Static\Release
ACTSharedLibraries = $(EVOACT)\OutPut\RV\Files\Shlib1\Release
VMACLibraries = $(EVOVMAC)\Output\RV\Lib\Files\Debug
EOSLibararuies = $(EOSSDK)\lib
GUISDKLibraries= $(GUISDK)\lib
VRXSDKLobraries= $(EVOSDK)\lib
VCARDSLOTLobraries= $(VCARDSLOT)\Output\RV\Files\Static

#
######################### Options for Tools ########################
#

############# Compiler Options  ############
Includes = -I$(ACTIncludes) -I$(EOSIncludes) -I$(GUIIncludes) -I$(CardslotInclude)

# for release version change the COptions to 
#COptions =  -DLOGSYS_FLAG -DVERIFONE
COptions =  -D_VERIFONE -DVERIFONE -DEVO -p -W -D ARM -D _ARM -g  -D _MAKE_VX_
VRXHDRPARAM= -s 300000 -h 4000000 

#
######################### Dependencies  ########################
#

AppObjects = $(ObjDir)\Main.o 


#Using ACT static library.
ACTLibs = \
$(ACTStaticLibraries)\act2000.a \
$(EOSLibararuies)\CEIF.o    \
$(EOSLibararuies)\svc_net.o  \
$(EOSLibararuies)\elog.o \
$(GUISDKLibraries)\libvxguisdk.so







#
#########################  sample Target Definition ########################
#

pseudoOut : $(OutDir)\Hello.out
         $(EVOSDK)\bin\vrxhdr $(VRXHDRPARAM) -l ceif.lib=N:/ceif.lib -l net.lib=N:/net.lib -l elog.lib=N:/elog.lib  $(OutDir)\Hello.out


$(OutDir)\Hello.out : $(AppObjects)
  $(EVOSDK)\bin\vrxcc -map -p   $(AppObjects) $(ACTLibs) -o Hello.out
    move  Hello.out $(OutDir)
    del  /F /Q $(ObjDir)\*.o


########################  Compile #########################


$(ObjDir)\Main.o : $(SrcDir)\Main.cpp 
    $(EVOSDK)\bin\vrxcc  -c  $(Includes)  $(COptions) $(SrcDir)\Main.cpp -e"-" | "$(DTKTOOLS)\fmterrorARM.exe"
    move Main.o $(ObjDir)\Main.o
```

please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Do you include the necessary header for `class VxGUI` in `main.cpp`?

Comment: i think "yes". it code was in the verifone samples. and included #include <svc.h>
#include <svc_gui.h>

Comment: Can you share the relevant lines in your makefile?

Comment: sure, i edited my question as you want

Comment: The error is a linker error, so it's definitely not releated to headers. The compilation phase was successful. Likely you need to revise the libraries list. I would remove the trailing backslash \ from the line `$(GUISDKLibraries)\libvxguisdk.so\\` it looks awful.

Comment: I revised that make file sufficiently . but not had been compile.

Answer (score 2):

Have fixed the problem above?
  If not, please pay attention that, when you use the libvxgui, you must use C++ syntax and generate a .vso file instead of .out bin file.

insert the -vsoapp option in the CC and Link options and the output must be .vso file.

COptions = -g -b -p -vsoapp -map -armcc,"--diag_suppress 1300\,611\,9,--apcs=/fpic --export_all_vtbl" -DLOGSYS_FLAG -DLOGSYS_NEW_API_STYLE

LOptions = -g -p -vsoapp -b -k -map

$(VRXSDK)/bin/vrxcc $(LOptions) $(AppObjects) $(Libs) -o $@

$(VRXSDK)/bin/vrxhdr -s $(STACK_SIZE) -h $(HEAP_SIZE) -lnet.lib=N:/net.lib -lceif.lib=N:/ceif.lib -lssl.lib=N:/ssl.lib -lelog.lib=N:/elog.lib $(OutDir)/$(OutFile)

$(ObjDir)/%.o: $(SrcFiles)/%.c 
    $(VRXSDK)/bin/vrxcc -c $(COptions) $(Includes) $< -o $@

$(ObjDir)/%.o: $(SrcFiles)/%.cpp
    $(VRXSDK)/bin/vrxcc -c $(COptions) $(Includes) $< -o $@

I have used VxGUI and including with QT Objects with success.
If you have more problems, let me know. I can send a working project to you.

Best regards,
Leandro

Comment: Just an additional comment. The binary name is .vsa

Comment: Hi @Leandro
thanks for your response
i made the smk file as you mentioned and width your COptions & LOptions.
but  after compile Main.O will be generate but show an error in linker.
the error is 'error MSB3073: The command NMAKE /i /f MakeFile.smk /a exited with code -1.'
I would appreciate if you let me have a simple project with vxguilib
my email is ahmdvnd@gmail.com
thank you

Comment: Hi @Leandro i get in same trouble. Can you send me that working project to understand where is my problem. behnia_k@yahoo.com. thank you